# Find the resolvent kernel of particular form of volterra integral equation of second kind

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Find the resolvent kernel for the integral equation
$$u(x)= 30 +6x+∫_0^x(5t-6t^2 )u(t)dt$$

I try to solve but its lengthy 
$$k(x,t)=(5t-6t^2)$$
$$k_2(x,t)=∫_ξ^x (5t-6t^2)(5ξ-6ξ^2)dt$$
its very lengthy how i find out $$k_3 $$ and$$k_n+1$$

Suppose that the kernel (x,t ) is a polynomial of degree (n − 1) in x, which can always
be represented in the form
$$a_0(x)+a_1(x)(x-t)$$
then how we take the values if a_0 and a_1

Answer (score 1):

By using the Laplace transform and the convolution theorem, examples found [here](http://www.math.ttu.edu/~gilliam/ttu/s14/chapter_4_lecture_notes.pdf), 
it is seen that for 
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}\{ f(t) \} = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- s t} f(t) \, dt = f(s)
\end{align} 
then the integral equation 
\begin{align}
u(t)= 30 + 6t + \int_{0}^{t} (5y-6y^2 )u(y)dy
\end{align}
becomes
\begin{align}
u(s)= \frac{30}{s} + \frac{6}{s^2} + \left(\frac{5}{s} - \frac{12}{s^3} \right) u(s).
\end{align}
By solving for $u(s)$ the result becomes
\begin{align}
u(s) = \frac{6 s + 30 s^2}{s^3 - 5 s + 12}.
\end{align}
Inversion of this yields
\begin{align}
u(t) = \frac{6}{77} \, e^{-3 t} \left[ 46 \sqrt{7} \, e^{\frac{9 t}{2}} \sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{7} t}{2} \right) + 238 \, e^{\frac{9 t}{2}} \cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{7} t}{2}\right) + 147 \right] .
\end{align}

Comment: we need to find out kernel $$k_1$$ to $$k_n$$

Comment: Any one solve it with alternative method